# Excel Web Access web part real time update

Tags: 2010, web-part, excel-services

I have the following scenario and would very much appreciate any advice:

I exported a list `/System/Examples` to Excel and then saved it as **Testing.xlsx** to a different document library: `/System/Documents`.

I have an Excel Web Access web part displaying a pivot table on a page: `/Admin/Dashboard.aspx`

I can then open the document from the Excel Web Access web part and enable the connection, modify the document and then save it. However, if I now refresh the connection, both my local document and Excel Web Access web part display the previous version (presumably cached) and the original document in `/System/Documents` is correctly updated with my new data.

If I now close the Excel document and click **"Reload workbook"** (not refresh connection) on the Excel Web Access web part, it will fetch my saved data.

Now, what I actually need it to do is for the Excel Web Access web part to display real time updates. Is there a way of doing this or is it just a case of manipulating the timeout values in the Trusted File Location properties in the Excel Services service application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @waqas in excel web app 2013 Is this feature available? we have maximum speed in sync and update unlike 2010? is this true?